# How to get boolean and numeric value OOB in json in AEM

Tags: extjs, aem

On Page I am having a dialog in which I have a numeric field. when I set any value in this field, under content folder in crx/de the value is coming as string. Also, in infinity json, it is coming as string only. Please see below

```
<Frequency
           jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
            allowBlank="false"
            dName="frequency"
            fieldLabel="Frequency(sec.):"
            name="./duration"
            xtype="numberfield"/>
```

Is there any way I can get integer value OOB. Else, I have to change this in js or java code. Please suggest.

Comment: could you post your dialog definition?

Comment: please see the changes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though you specify an xtype of numberfield, AEM will persist the value as a String in CRX repository. You will have to use Typehints to persist in a different datatype. Refer [this](http://blogs.adobe.com/livecycle/2011/12/beyond-string-typehint-to-rescue.html)

Here's the xml i just tried

```
<Frequency
       jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
       allowBlank="false"
        fieldLabel="Frequency(sec.):"
        name="./duration"
        xtype="numberfield"/>
<FrequencyHint
           jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
            defaultValue="Long"
            name="./duration@TypeHint"
            value="Long" 
            xtype="hidden"/>
```

duration persisted as long:

[image: duration persisted as long]

As per sling [docs](http://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/manipulating-content-the-slingpostservlet-servlets-post.html#typehint), you should be able to persist as Boolean, Decimal, Long, multi-value property can also be added.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I have tested this and this is working fine.